# Why does VS Code NOT throw "Cannot find module 'typescript'. ts(2307)" when the module is NOT there in js files?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, import

I am using VScode with several react apps. For one of my projects, in the .js files I do not get the "Cannot find module 'typescript'. ts(2307)" alert on `import something from './an/incorrect/path'` lines, where I would expect that ts2307 alert.

However I do get that alert in .ts files that import from incorrect paths.

How do I get those alerts to appear as well in .js files?

I've checked that both of these settings are set to true in VScode settings.json.
You want to change these two settings in VS Code's settings.json:

```
"typescript.validate.enable": true,
"javascript.validate.enable": true,
```

This is my tsconfig file.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "outDir": "lib"
    },
    "include": ["./**/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer, right after I considered that typescript checking might be entirely disabled for .js files. Then I found I had to add `"checkJs": true` to the compilerOptions in tsconfig.json.

ts2307 are now correctly shown when trying to import from incorrect file paths.